# how to measure quality of service of network performance on client side

Tags: socket.io, web-performance

I'm currently working on end of studies project. The main subject is on measuring quality of service of webs browsing performance on client side. I have searched a lot, and I didn't found any way or language to make this work. 
I found Socket.io api that communicates in real time with browser client side.
Is it able to realize what I want ?
Are there are any other way ?
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, what you are looking for is called RUM (Real User Monitoring). There is a bunch of tools that can measure browser-side performances, and send them back to a server.

There is an open source project called Boomerang: https://www.tollmanz.com/rum-monitoring-boomerang-boomcatch-datadog/

Here is one of the numerous SAS tools for RUM: https://newrelic.com/browser-monitoring. You can also look at Soasta, Cedexis, Webperf.io, ...

If you want to build your own solution because these solutions don't fit your needs, you probably don't need real time synchronization with the server with web sockets. Just send a beacon back to the server with a simple HTTP request.